# Push notification & UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm working with push notifications, i send a push with the flag content-available set to "true", i would like to know if when i receive this kind of push, the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification is fired to wake up the app, because there are some methods that are called only when the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification is fired to the system

Answer (score 0):

If your app is properly enabled and configured to receive background pushes then when a background push arrives your app's  didReceiveRemoteNotification: *may* get called if the app is in the background.

If the app was terminated by the OS then the app *may* be relaunched by the OS when the push arrives and the push payload forwarded to it.

If the app was terminated by the user then the app will not get relaunched by the OS when the push arrives.

I say *may* because with iOS 8 Apple have drastically changed when a background push is delivered to the app. There are several factors involved, but the major major major factor is if your iPhone is being charged (via either a direct power supply or via a usb cable connected to a computer). If your iPhone is being charged then the background push will get delivered (unless the user terminated the app), however if the iPhone is not being charged at the moment the push arrives, then the majority of the time the push will not get delivered to the app.

In addition to this, the behavior when using the Apple sandbox environment is not consistent when using the Apple production environment. So you can develop and test your app using the sandbox environment (as everybody does) and everything may look like it is working fine. Then when you actually switch to the production environment it will not - this is because background pushes sent over the sandbox environment generally tend in my experience to be delivered more often to a background app then if they are sent over the production environment.